# How to include data in a URL for a Google Apps Script web app to read?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made my first little test web app and have that "technology" working, as per:
[image]

The next step is to enable a customer to be able to click on a status URL in an email so they can view the scheduling status of their job. So, the question:

**Is it possible to create a URL which the webapp can then parse and pull data for?**

A URL something like:
https://script.google.com/a/macros/example.com/s/AKfycbwMgBLtVP8Ur8GKNpGxxjna_zr5BlegmvlFqXQW1g6q5UfksAg/exec/**+123+sample+street+samplesuburb**

and then the web app would pull and display the scheduling info related to that address.

Many thanks ~

Comment: Add code as text instead as image. Think on screen readers, copy the code to an answer, etc.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inspect the 'e' object of the doGet() function to get URL parameters

```
 // yourUrl/?a=1&b=2&c=3&c=4

function doGet(e){

 e.queryString // will be a=1&b=2&c=3&c=4
 e.parameter; // will be {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}. For parameters that have multiple values, this only returns the first value
 e.parameters; // will be {"a": ["1"], "b": ["2"], "c": ["3", "4"]}. Returns array of values for each key.



}
```

See 'URL parameters' section here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: I got it working and have a virtual smile from ear to ear. Thank you Anton, this is just GREAT.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: i don't get it. What's `e` and how do we set a value into `e`?

Comment: You don't set any values into e. E is an event object passed to the doGet function as soon as doGet receives an incoming HTTP request. You can then inspect the event object and extract the details you need. Please refer to Apps Script Docs

Answer (score 4):

As a working test, I used:

A web app URL with a parameter, like:
https://script.google.com/a/macros/example.com/s/AKfycbwMgBLhu88Ur8GKNpGxxjna_zr5BlegmvlFqXQW1g6q5UPksAg/exec?street=65_Fields_Ave
...with "street=65_Fields_Ave" concatenated to the web app URL from spreadsheet data for a specific customer, to be included in their Booking email.

And read the street like (the real script will test for suburb too):

```
function doGet(e) {
  var paramStreet = e.parameter.street;          // format like "123_Sample_Street"
  var street = paramStreet.replace(/#|_/g,' ');  // format like "123 Sample Street"
```

Then searched for the row in the spreadsheet and presented the data via:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
html.name = fullName;
html.street = street;
html.status = schedStatus;

return html.evaluate();
```

And in the HTML file:

```
<div> 
  <h1>Scheduling Status</h1>
  <p>Primary Contact: <?= name; ?></p>
  <p>Street: <?= street; ?></p>
  <p>Status: <?= status; ?>
</div>
```

Note that the web app needs to be published as a new version after each change:
[image]

Works like a charm! Thank you [Anton Dementiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586528/anton-dementiev).